# Visual Studio Qt develop Sqlite3 transaction

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt

What is the correct using of a transaction in Qt Sqlite3?
I use Visual Studio 2022 to develop a Qt application.
here is the part of Code:

```
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QDebug>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("dst.db");
    if (!db.open()) {
        //can't open db
        return 1;
    }

    QSqlQuery* query1 = new QSqlQuery(db);

    db.transaction();

    if (!query1->exec("create table test(u,p);"))
    {
        qDebug() << "create table [fail]\n";

    }

    if (!query1->exec("INSERT INTO test(u,p) VALUES ('tangying','332233');"))
    {
        qDebug() << "insert data [fail]\n";

    }

    //the result of this query should be failed or the result or committing should be failed
    // because the table `tes` not exist
    // the correct result should be that all work should rollback
    //but the previous query execute successfully in the database

    if (!query1->exec("INSERT INTO tes(u,p) VALUES ('tangying','332233');"))
    {
        qDebug() << "insert data2 [fail]\n";

    }



    if (!db.commit())
    {

        qDebug() << "commit [fail]";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I use the following code in Navicat for Sqlite,all work rollback in Database.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
create table test(u,p);
INSERT INTO test(u,p) VALUES ('tangying','332233');
INSERT INTO tes(u,p) VALUES ('tangying','332233');
COMMIT;
```

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;     OK
create table test(u,p);       OK
INSERT INTO test(u,p) VALUES ('tangying','332233');      Affected rows:1
INSERT INTO tes(u,p) VALUES ('tangying','332233');       No such table
```

When I refresh table list,all work not be executed.
What is the correct using of a transaction in Qt Sqlite3?

Comment: Whats the return value of `db.transaction();`, i.e. is the transaction even supported by your driver? see doc "QSqlDatabase::transaction(): Begins a transaction on the database if the driver supports transactions. Returns true if the operation succeeded. Otherwise it returns false." https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqldatabase.html#transaction

Comment: the return value of db.transaction() is true. I tested it before I asked this question.